# Python crashes with SFrame

Tags: python, graphlab, sframe

I am doing a course on ML on Coursera. I am using graphlab for this course

When I execute the below line, my python gets crashed. Please help me in solving this. I have no clue why it crashes everytime

```
sf = graphlab.SFrame('people-example.csv')
```

[image: Picture of Python crashing]

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do to fix this (on my firewalled Windows 10 system). First I completely uninstalled Anaconda2 and reinstalled it from scratch.

Second go to Turi, register and download the GraphLab license file.

Then in a browser go to pypi.python.org/simple/ and download the GraphLab-Create (currently file GraphLab_Create-2.1-py2.7.tar.gz)

Now open a CMD window as Administrator on your system.

Using the install license info (registration email and license number) from Turi run the command to install GraphLab License like so:

```
pip install --upgrade -U --no-cache-dir http://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/registrationemail@mail.com/F8DC-YOUR-LICEN-HERE-0000-0000-0000-000/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz --trusted-host get.graphlab.com
```

Now install the sources you downloaded from Python like this:

```
pip install --upgrade  -U --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org   ./GraphLab_Create-2.1-py2.7.tar.gz
```

Finally open Python and run the following:

```
import graphlab as gl
gl.get_dependencies()
```

Answer (score 0):

SFrame syntax requires that you use:

```
sf = graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('people-example.csv')
```

That should would, I'm not sure why python would crash as result of incorrect syntax.

Comment: It crashes just like that

Comment: I was trying to read .gl, not csv

Getting this every time - The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Comment: In your example it looks like your trying to load a csv file. You may need to check what you file name is, remove '.csv', or potentialy add '.gl'. Additionally you need to use graphlab.load_sframe() instead of graphlab.SFrame().

Comment: Same happens when i use the function load_sframe()